# php/Drupal - list all nodes that a given user to permission to edit

Tags: api, drupal, module

I have a function that lists all nodes on the system. I would like to refine this to show only nodes that current user is able to edit - either with API or SQL statement. (Drupal 6)

```
function fnGetNodeTypes($typeOfNodes) {
    $string = "";
    $types_of_nodes  = array_keys(node_get_types());
    $string .= "<select name='typeOfNodes'>";
    $string .= "<option value=''>Please select</option> ";
    $string .= "<option value='all'>All</option> ";

    foreach($types_of_nodes as $node){      
        if($typeOfNodes == $node ){
            $selected = "selected";
        }
        else{
            $selected = "";
        }       
        $string .= "<option $selected value=\"" . $node . "\">" . $node ;
        $string .= "</option>\n";
    }
    $string .= "</select\n>";
    return $string;
}
```

#### Update:

Following @chx suggestion I tried messing around with users, users_roles and permissions.  Let me know if there is a more Drupal way of doing this.

```
//----------------------------------------------
// Contruct select/option box of node types
//----------------------------------------------
function fnGetNodeTypes($typeOfNodes) {
    $string = "";
    $types_of_nodes  = array_keys(node_get_types());
    $string .= "<select name='typeOfNodes'>";
    $string .= "<option value=''>Please select</option> ";
    //$string .= "<option value='all'>All</option> ";
    foreach($types_of_nodes as $node_type){         
        if (fnInArray($node_type))
        {
            if($typeOfNodes == $node_type ){
                $selected = "selected";
            }
            else{
                $selected = "";
            }       
            $string .= "<option $selected value=\"" . $node_type . "\">" . $node_type ;
            $string .= "</option>\n";
        }
    }
    $string .= "</select\n>";
    return $string;
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------
//  function fnInArray - see if user is allowed to edit this node type
//---------------------------------------------------------------------

function fnInArray($node_type)
{
    global $user;

    if ($user->name == 'admin') { return TRUE; }

    // get list of all nodes that user is allowed to access
    // 
    $string =   " SELECT permission.perm as permission_perm "  .
        " from users " .
        " join users_roles  on ( users_roles.uid = users.uid ) " .
        " join permission on (permission.rid = users_roles.rid) " .
        " where  users.name = '" . $user->name . "'";

    $result = db_query($string);
    while ($row = db_fetch_object($result)) {           
        $pieces = explode(", " , $row->permission_perm);        
        $node_name = "edit any " . trim($node_type) . " content";
        if (in_array($node_name, $pieces )) 
        {
            return TRUE;        
        }
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly impossible to do. Node access can be specified by a hook so the only *generic* way to do that would be to retrieve every. single. node. and run `node_access($node, 'update')` on them. That's not too fast. You can mess around with node types, permissions, the node access table etc depending on how your site is set up and modules are used. If we presume that the only thing controlling your nodes are the permissions and understand please this presumption is not always true by far, then in Drupal 6 and below (I suspect from `node_get_types()` you are not using D7) you would indeed iterate over `node_get_types()`and check `user_access("edit own $type content") || user access("edit any $type content")` but this won't go too far.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure of the proper method for Drupal 6 (check [db_rewrite_sql](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database.inc/function/db_rewrite_sql/6)) but for Drupal 7, while you are building your query add addTag('node_access') to the query and that will limit it to only nodes that the user has permission to edit. If you go to the link for db_rewrite_sql above make sure to take a look at the comments.

Answer (score 0):

[db_query](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database.mysql-common.inc/function/db_query/6) + [db_rewrite_sql](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database.inc/function/db_rewrite_sql/6): Returns only the rows the logged-in user is allowed to view.

```
$results = db_query(db_rewrite_sql($query), $args);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what the Module Grants Monitor module is for http://drupal.org/project/module_grants. From the project page: "Clicking on it reveals a summary of all the content the logged-in user has access to (i.e. view, edit) after access controls have been applied by the content access modules installed on your site". I installed and tested this today and it seems to work. Does anyone have comments or experience with this module?

It seems like this should also be possible with Views or Rules... but maybe that's just because everything seems possible with them...